# What occurs when assigning a string to char in C

Tags: c, string, char

I would appreciate your help with understanding what exactly occur in the next code? (writing "a" instead of 'a' and  etc...). I mean what will be stored in the memory and why isnt the program crashes.

```
char str[10] ; 
str[0] = "a";
str[1] = "b";
str[2] = "\0";
```

Thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't even compile!

Comment: 'a' is a `char` "a" is a `const char*`. you are trying to assing a `char*` to a `char`

Comment: "incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to `char`"

Comment: Actually, `"a"` is not a `const char *`. `"a"` is a an `array 2 of char`. In the statement `str[0] = "a";`, `"a"` evaluates to a `char *`. While it is true that attempting to modify a string literal results in Undefined Behavior, it does not have `const` type.

Answer (score 2):

'a' is a single character (type `char`) having the ASCII value 97.
"a" is a C style string, a `char` array having two elements, 'a' and '\0'.

If you compile your code above you will get three warnings for the three assignments. On GCC these warnings say something like this:

```
main.c:6:12: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

Lets take the first assignment in your code:

```
str[0] = "a";
```

The right hand side operand, "a", is a `char *`. The left hand side operand is a `char`, which is an integer type. As the warning hints towards, it takes the value of the pointer, converts it to integer, and then truncates it to the size of `char` and stores the truncated value in `str[0]`. So after the assignment `str[0]` will not contain the value 'a' (ASCII 97) as you might expect, but some value obtained as described above.

So far so good, no reason for the program to crash, just note that `str` will not contain any meaningful string.

Now if you try to do something useful with that string, like print it for example:

```
printf("%s", str);
```

you find a reason that might crash the program (or cause a whole lot of other problems, like memory corruption).
The problem is that the last assignment, `str[2] = "\0"`, doesn't properly terminate the string as you might expect. So you end up with a C-style string that's not properly NULL-terminated. This is a sure and short path to disaster.

To test this behavior, try to display the actual values stored in `str` after those assignments:

```
printf("%d - %d - %d", str[0], str[1], str[2]);
```

You will most likely find different values than the ones you might expect (97, 98, 0).

Comment: Right hand side that is the C style string is of `const char*` type

Comment: @UchiaItachi Incorrect. String literals do not have `const` type in C.

Answer (score 2):

C allows it, but it doesn't do what you expect it to. For the first one (`str[0]` and `"a"`), what the compiler does is convert the character array the compiler creates from `"a"` and decays it to a pointer, it then converts this pointer to a `char`.

So what is stored in `str[0]` is the last byte of the *address* of the array of the string literal `"a"`.

Comment: More likely, what is stored is one byte of the value of the address, or some other garbage value resulting from the conversion of a pointer (likely a 4-byte or 8-byte value) into a `char` (one byte.)

Answer (score 0):

Simplistic terms...
Take this for an example,
-Image an array as a Rack with lots of shelves.
-String are basically like an array of chars.
-Chars are like knick-knacks.
'a' is a char and "a" is a string.
Reworded: 'a' is a knick-knack and "a" is a rack with a knick-knack 'a' in it.
Str[10] is a rack with 10 shelves.
Now doing this, Str[0] = "a"; is like shoving a rack with a knick-knack 'a' in it, on to the first shelf of another rack...

So it's like shoving a whole rack into another rack, and then expect it to have it fit...

Even if this answer has no logic at all, its just to show that, str[0] = "a"; makes absolutely no sense either. You might as well just do str[0] = 97; to just completely forget about quotes.. :P

Comment: What is a knick-knack? I looked on [Wikipedia](en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knick_Knack) bit it seems unrelated.

Comment: knick-knacks are like small ornements or toys, etc. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?rd=1&word=knick-knack